# Add information above a custom post type listing of all posts page

Tags: custom-post-types, hooks

Ok, that sounds like a rather confusing title, let me explain.

I have created a custom post type (CPT) and I want to add some summary information about the posts of that post type above their listing (where the filter and bulk action buttons are), the page in question would be:

```
http://www.example.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type={cpt}
```

Is there a hook for this ? Since I don’t really know what to call this area, i am not finding anything doing any further searches.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What theme are you using?

Comment: @BradDalton theme, which is self developed in this case, has nothing to do with it, it is an admin screen which im trying to edit; not a frontend one. Thanks for trying to help out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`admin_notices`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) action for that:

```
function wpa_admin_notice() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if( 'your_post_type' == $screen->post_type
        && 'edit' == $screen->base ){
        ?>
        <div class="updated">
            <p>Here is some text</p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpa_admin_notice' );
```

Change `your_post_type` to whatever your custom post type slug is.
Also see [`get_current_screen`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) for more info on that function.

Comment: thanks, should have thought about admin_notices ! Thanks again, saved me hours of wracking my brain :)